# Teamcity: add select type parameter, not selected by default

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, teamcity, teamcity-10, team-city-10.0

TC 10.0

I have a configuration and select parameter(drop-down menu) in it.
How i can set this parameter to not selected - user must select it, otherwise  configuration will fail or will not start?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can make it deselected. The best thing you can do is probably this:

- in the parameter properties dialog, click *Edit...*
- set *Display* to *Prompt*
- keep *Read-only* unchecked
- keep *Allow multiple* unchecked

This way, when the user runs the build, even using the simple *Run* button (as opposed to the *Run...* for custom builds), they will be prompted to select the value. Unfortunately, the first value will be automatically selected, so the user isn't *forced* to think about it.

On the other hand, you do need a default value anyway, because when builds are triggered non-manually (by commits or schedule), they must know which value to run with.